# Iterate over columns of array as column vectors

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to iterate over the columns of a 2D numpy array such that the iterators remain column vectors?

i.e.

```
>>> A = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
>>> np.hstack([a in some_way_of_iterating(A)])
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
```

This is useful, for example, when I want to pass the column vectors into a function that transforms the individual column vector without having to clutter stuff with reshapes

Answer (score 2):

How about simple transpose:

```py
B = np.hstack([a.reshape(-1,1) for a in A.T])
```

You require `.reshape(-1,1)` to get size of `n X 1` instead of just `n`

Answer (score 0):

An ugly but another possible way with `index` and `transpose`:

```
np.hstack([A[:,i][np.newaxis].T for i in range(len(A.T))])
```

I am using `np.newaxis` to facilitate the transpose. Based on  @hpaulj suggestion this can be significantly cleaned off:

```
np.hstack([A[:,i,np.newaxis] for i in range(A.shape[1])])
```

**Output**:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: `A[:, i, np.newaxis]` isn't as ugly.   Also `range(A.shape[1])`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [39]: A = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
In [40]: A
Out[40]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Iteration on an array operates on the first dimension.  It's much like iterating on a nested list - but slower.  And like the list case it too reduces the dimension.

You could iterate on the range, and use advanced indexing, `[i]` to maintain the 2d, "column vector" shape:

```
In [41]: [A[:,[i]] for i in range(3)]
Out[41]: 
[array([[1],
        [4],
        [7]]),
 array([[2],
        [5],
        [8]]),
 array([[3],
        [6],
        [9]])]
```

Or iterate on the transpose - but this still requires some form of `reshape`.  I prefer the `None/newaxis` syntax.

```
In [42]: [a[:,None] for a in A.T]
Out[42]: 
[array([[1],
        [4],
        [7]]),
 array([[2],
        [5],
        [8]]),
 array([[3],
        [6],
        [9]])]
```

Indexing and reshape can be combined with:

```
In [43]: A[:,0,None]
Out[43]: 
array([[1],
       [4],
       [7]])
```

Or with slicing:

```
In [44]: A[:,1:2]
Out[44]: 
array([[2],
       [5],
       [8]])
```

There is a difference that may matter.  `A[:,[i]]` makes a copy, `A[:,i,None]` is a `view`.

This may be the time to reread the basic `numpy` indexing docs.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html